# how to compare js array values with a string

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON array and I want to compare its values with a String. For Example, My JSON Array is

```
{
  "slot": ["10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "03:30 PM"]
}
```

Now I am trying to access it in this way:

```
for (i in data.slot) {
  console.log(slot[i] === "10:00 AM"); //this return false
  if (slot[i] === "10:00 AM") btn1.disabled = true;
  if (slot[i] === "10:30 AM") btn2.disabled = true;
  if (slot[i] === "03:00 PM") btn3.disabled = true;
  if (slot[i] === "03:30 PM") btn4.disabled = true;
}
```

Now whenever I am trying to compare it, the if statement returns false and the button doesn't get disabled. I got to know this on the Chrome Dev console. Any Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: That should work. You should use `else if` since the comparisons are mututally exclusive, but it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: It should log `true` for `i == 0`, and `false` for all other iterations.

Comment: Just write `let data = {...}`

Comment: And idk why it is not working like I looked into Chrome Dev Console for the values I am getting and that is also right

Comment: yes ``else if`` because your loop statements is all valid, so all buttons get disabled

Comment: No actually its totally opposite, My all buttons are enabled. i want them to be disabled according to the data that I am getting from the json array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to address the right variable

```
data.slot[i]
^^^^^
```

```js
const data = { slot: ["10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "03:30 PM"] }

for (let i in data.slot) {
  console.log(data.slot[i] === "10:00 AM"); // true false false
  if (data.slot[i] === "10:00 AM")
    btn1.disabled = true;
  if (data.slot[i] === "10:30 AM")
    btn2.disabled = true;
  if (data.slot[i] === "03:00 PM")
    btn3.disabled = true;
  if (data.slot[i] === "03:30 PM")
    btn4.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1">1</button>
<button id="btn2">2</button>
<button id="btn3">3</button>
<button id="btn4">4</button>
```

A better approach takes the value directly by iterating with [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```js
const data = { slot: ["10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "03:30 PM"] }

for (const value of data.slot) {
    console.log(value === "10:00 AM"); // true false false
    if (value === "10:00 AM") btn1.disabled = true;
    if (value === "10:30 AM") btn2.disabled = true;
    if (value === "03:00 PM") btn3.disabled = true;
    if (value === "03:30 PM") btn4.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1">1</button>
<button id="btn2">2</button>
<button id="btn3">3</button>
<button id="btn4">4</button>
```

Comment: Hi @Nina Scholz You are absolutely correct. I know this could work like this but my json array is coming from a servlet and Idk why it is not working

Comment: Hi @Nina Scholz your 2nd solution runs PERFECTLY. THANKS, A TONNN !!!!!

Comment: maybe you have no data or need to parse the JSON **string**.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = {
  slot: ["10:00 AM", "10:30 AM", "03:30 PM"],
};

for (i in data.slot) {
  const _slot = data.slot[i];
  console.log(_slot === "10:00 AM");
  if (_slot === "10:00 AM") btn1.disabled = true;
  if (_slot === "10:30 AM") btn2.disabled = true;
  if (_slot === "03:00 PM") btn3.disabled = true;
  if (_slot === "03:30 PM") btn4.disabled = true;
}
```